# ADX Connection on Landing page

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, adxstudio-portals

thanks for reading my question.

- D365 v8.2
- ADX Portal 7.0.0025
- Build the ADX Sample Portal (C:\Program Files (x86)\ Adxstudio\ XrmPortals\ 7.0.0025\Samples\MasterPortal)
- Update the Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies v8.2 from NuGet

While browsing the landing page (first page) of ADX Portal, I'm getting the following exception:-

Even, I tried changing

- Dynamics CRM Organization Service URL:
  https://abcxyzdev.crm6.dynamics.com
- Dynamics CRM Organization Service    URL:
  https://abcxyzdev.api.crm6.dynamics.com
- Installed Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies from Nuget and tried
  8.0, 8.1, 8.2 versions.
  [image]
  Your input is appreciated!!

Comment: Why did you "Update the Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies v8.2 from NuGet"?

Comment: Thanks @JamesWood. You can check this link and they mentioned to update it (https://www.quantacrm.com/2017/01/24/dynamics-365-adxstudio-portals-compatibility-issue/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up a security protocol explicit to 'tls2'?

Below syntax might be helpful:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

Comment: Are you still facing this issue?